# jersey + spring + hibernate configuration issue getting null pointer exception for @autowired

Tags: spring, nullpointerexception, jersey, integration

hi i am getting null pointer exception in my application , i want to know my web.xml is correct or wrong,also i am using jar files not MAVEN

```
 `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app version="2.4"xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/n/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"><context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/Helloweb-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webresources/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping><servlet>
  <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> </servlet>  <servlet-mapping><servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>  </servlet-mapping></web-app>
```

Comment: can i use both dispatcher servlet and spring servlet in my web.xml? i am new to webservices plz clarify me on this,

Comment: exception stack trace please. Which line throws null pointer?

Comment: Maybe the Component scan is missing for the package of the object you are autowiring

Comment: exception at @Autowired property not initialized

Comment: component scan is there in my servlet configuration file

Comment: Have you configured @Autowired bean in dispatcher-servlet.xml?